# Not allow url in textarea value

Tags: html, textarea

I have a contact form in which I have a textarea.
I'd like to not allow to submit if the textarea value contains a url.

I tried with html pattern but not effects
for example : `<textarea pattern="[^http:|https]"`

Any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Validate it with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate using Javascript like below:

```
var b = url.search(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g);
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uzo8j806/9/

Comment: Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/francoisd/uzo8j806/

I tried to highlight the textarea on submit when url is in textarea in order to not submit it